# Error copying files to blob storage - Azure

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I am trying to upload files using Jenkins to Azure blob storage while uploading files AZCopy asks for confirmation which ends up in error.

```
[2018/03/09 10:11:11][WARNING] Incomplete operation with different 
command line detected at the journal directory 
"/var/lib/jenkins/Microsoft/Azure/AzCopy".
 Do you want to overwrite the journal to start a new operation? Choose 
 Yes to overwrite, choose No to cancel current operation. (Yes/No) 
 [2018/03/09 10:11:11][ERROR] The operation was canceled because user 
 chose not to overwrite the existing journal file.
  [Pipeline] }
```

Can anyone please help with this error, how can I force azcopy to overwrite files?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [/y option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#y) to suppress the confirmation and overwrite forcibly.

> /Y
>
> Suppresses all AzCopy confirmation prompts. This option also allows the use of write-only SAS tokens for data upload scenarios, when /XO and /XN are not specified

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but try adding this flag

```
--overwrite=[true|false|ifSourceNewer|prompt]
```

Got answer from [AzCopy Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy#options)